# Corporate apps for Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Apple has a corporate developer program with an elevated licensing cost, does Microsoft provide such a service for Windows Phone 7 developers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was asked at a recent MS event. You can assign (I think 5) phones to developer unlock them, then load application directly/bypass the marketplace.

Also, there were talks that they are hoping to soon allow beta/redemption codes to allow limited deployment of your application to non-unlocked phones, bypassing testing/marketplace acceptance.... But I do not know the status of this.

The best thing you can do at the moment is develop your application as normal and have a password/login screen at startup. This is a horrible approach, but it does work.

At the moment, the phone is very much targeted towards consumers.

Comment: Will it pass Microsoft QA to the app store if it's a case of username/password?

Comment: @meds - I doubt they will be able to test it fully - however, if you explain it is an internal app/have a contact at MS, I am sure it will pass (well this was my impression).... The testing is really there to protect the average consumer buying/paying, downloading then crashing.

Comment: but the app would still be subject to normal MS QA timing... so it wouldn't be very feasible, especially if you have a business critical update or app you need to push through urgently...

Comment: Locking down full access to the app by requiring a password to log in is likely to fail marketplace testing UNLESS the application is still workable in some form without doing so.

Comment: Password protected apps can certainly pass the Marketplace requirements - however, you need to supply the testers with a demo username/password. Also you get 3 unlocked phones, not 5.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is provided in the Apple Enterprise version, but so far Microsoft only has the one registration process and no private app distribution: you can distribute apps on the market to everyone, or by giving your xap file to people with dev-unlocked phones, nothing in between.

Answer (score 0):

The official line is NO, not yet.

Windows Phone 7 was created, first and foremost, for consumers, not enterprise customers.
That being said, LOTS of people are asking for this and Microsoft have said they will address this in the future. No timescales or details have yet been announced yet.

This will likely be related to the way that beta testing and home brew distribution are implemented. (Just my assumption.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I can't just comment on another answer in this thread, so my apologies for placing these remarks in an answer.

I think MS needs to really make this happen since it could be the saving grace for WP7. While I personally feel that my experience with WP7 and my Samsung Focus have been just as good or better than that with the second-gen iPod Touch that I have, there are a lot of people who aren't convinced. For better or worse, it really is the ecosystem that matters and MS has that within the corporate world.